# Raising error while installing sass

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems

I've installed ruby 2.3.3 on my system. Now, I'm trying to install sass but the following error is raising:

```
C:\>gem -v
2.5.2

C:\>gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENETRESET)
The connection has been broken due to keep-alive
e while the operation was in progress. - recvfrom(2)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Tried this: http://www.microsoftfixit.net/the-connection-has-been-broken-due-to-keep-alive-activity-detecting-a-failure-while-the-operation-was-in-progress/ ?

Comment: This doesn't work. I guess the problem is all about proxy setting or something. I connected to the Internet though an ISA server.